# Correct sizes attribute for img with srcset in a fluid, padded, media-queried container?

Tags: html, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to implement the new `srcset` attribute for `<img>` and I've run into some edge cases that are not working or I'm missing something.

I'm using the picturefill 2.1.0 polyfill, and I've read some articles like http://ericportis.com/posts/2014/srcset-sizes/ or https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#embedded-content.

I get the idea of very simple examples, e.g:

```
<img
    src="small.jpg"
    srcset="
        small.jpg  100w,
        medium.jpg 200w,
        large.jpg  300w
    "
    sizes="100vw"
>
```

The browser loads small.jpg, medium.jpg or large.jpg depending on screen size, pixel density, zoom and other factors. It may load medium.jpg for a 200px simple screen or a 100px hdpi(2x) display. So far so good.

The problem relies on the `sizes` attribute. In the previous example we are telling the browser that the picture takes up the whole (100%) viewpoint width (vw).

The project I'm working in uses Foundation, which has **fluid**, **em-padded** grids that may have more or less columns based on screen sizes (media queries).

Let's say, for instance, that we want a grid in which small screens have 2 columns, and medium screens (`min-width: 40em`) 4 columns. Every column contains an image. What would be the correct `sizes` keeping in mind that each column is width-fluid and has a padding defined in `em`s?

```
<ul class="small-block-grid-2 medium-block-grid-4">
    <li>
        <img
            src="small.jpg"
            srcset="
                small.jpg  160w,
                medium.jpg 320w,
                large.jpg  480w
            "
        >
    </li>
</ul>
```

1. `sizes="(min-width: 40em) 25vw,  50vw"`
2. `sizes="(min-width: 40em) ???em, ???em"`
3. `sizes="(min-width: 40em) ???px, ???px"`

The `vw` approach ignores the padding of the columns. The `em` or `px` approach ignores the fact that columns are fluid (and I'm not even sure which values should they have).

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use calc: i.e: calc(25vw - 4em)

Comment: @alexanderfarkas Thanks! It seems to work fine. Do you know if `em`s are relative to root font-size or `img`'s container font-size?

Comment: @alexanderfarkas One more doubt: Do you know if the `sizes` attribute is only used while pre-loading images? I mean, if I say that an `<img>` is `100vw`, but for some reason I'm wrong, or the page changes via JS, or whatever, and the image becomes 50vw, the browser will be smart enough to ignore my `100vw` declaration and pick up the correct file?

Comment: No, you need to add the correct sizes attribute. This is mandatory. In case the page changes via js you need to change the sizes accordingly. In case you are using JS it is quite simply, because then you can simply add a simple 'px' value.

Comment: use `data-interchange` how to is in the answer bellow.

Comment: The em is always using the default font-size (i.e. same as media queries), which means it's mostly 16px. It doesn't take into account any CSS changes by the author. In case you are struggling to generate the right sizes attribute. Maybe the following lazyLoader, which I created might help: https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes. Here an example markup: https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes#recommended-markup-lqip and here a demo: http://afarkas.github.io/lazysizes/#examples

Answer (score 1):

Well Foundation doesn't work like that, for the moment they are use javascript [`data-interchange`](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/interchange.html) to deal with the new attr [`srcset`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content.html#the-picture-element):

```
<img 
     data-interchange="[/path/to/default.jpg, (default)], 
     [/path/to/small.jpg, (small)], 
     [/path/to/retina.jpg, (retina)], 
     [/path/to/medium.jpg, (medium)], 
     [/path/to/bigger-image.jpg, (large)]"
>

<!-- or your own queries -->
<img 
     data-interchange="[/path/to/default.jpg, (only screen and (min-width: 1px))], 
     [/path/to/bigger-image.jpg, (only screen and (min-width: 1280px))]"
>
```

**Using Interchange With Images**

```
data-interchange="[image_path, (media query)], [image_path, (media query)]"
```

**Using Retina Images**

```
data-interchange="[image/path/to/retina.jpg, (retina)]"
```

**Custom Named Queries**

```
$(document).foundation('interchange', {
  named_queries : {
    my_custom_query : 'only screen and (max-width: 200px)'
  }
});
```

In your case you could just make new custom Named Queries and pass it to your Img.